# I want to access database from google maps API to show Markers as per database longitude latitude value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

```
var demoCtrl = this;
      NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        demoCtrl.map = map;
      });
      demoCtrl.stores = {
        foo: { position:[41, -87]},
        bar:{ position:[41, -83]}
      };
      demoCtrl.showStore = function(evt, storeId) {
        demoCtrl.store = demoCtrl.stores[storeId];
        demoCtrl.map.showInfoWindow('foo', this);
      };
      demoCtrl.mouseover = function() {
        console.log('mouseover');
      };
```

above is the code of javascript for google maps api

```
<info-window id="foo" on-mouseover="demoCtrl.mouseover()">
  <div ng-non-bindable="">
    Lat: {{anchor.getPosition().lat()}}<br/>
    Lng: {{anchor.getPosition().lng()}}<br/>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='item in demoCtrl.store.items'>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</info-window>

<marker ng-repeat="(id, store) in demoCtrl.stores" id="{{id}}"
  position="{{store.position}}"
  on-click="demoCtrl.showStore(event, id)"></marker>

<info-window id="bar" on-mouseover="demoCtrl.mouseover()">
  <div ng-non-bindable="">
    Lat: {{anchor.getPosition().lat()}}<br/>
    Lng: {{anchor.getPosition().lng()}}<br/>
  </div>
</info-window>

<marker position="41, -79" on-click="demoCtrl.map.showInfoWindow('bar')" />
```

Here i want my custom value of longitude and latitude from my database i am getting value from database but i am unable to show it on Map can anyone help how to get value on Map.

Comment: What is the issue? Any errors? Any part of the google documentation that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, issue. I am unable to get value from database on Map